# User array in collection2 in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collection2

How can I store userid's of meteor account-users in a collection2 array. My definition of schema looks like. Will this work?

I wanted an approach to add associated users to a collection. Whereby I wanted to control who are allowed to see this particular document of the collection. Is there a better way to do this than how I'm modelling.

```js
name: {
    type: String,
    max: 100,
    optional: false
  },
  billingAddress: {
    type: AddressSchema
  },
  shippingAddress: {
    type: [AddressSchema]
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    max: 20,
    allowedValues: ['Vendor', 'Customer', 'Self', 'Employee'],
    optional: false
  },
  phones: {
    type: [String]
  },
  emails: {
    type: [String],
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
  },
  website: {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.url
  },
  isCustomer: {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: false
  },
  isVendor: {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: false
  },
  isSearchable: {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: false
  },
  associatedUsers: {
    type: [Meteor.users]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each document receives an `_id` automatically. It isn't recommended to put `_id` in the schema. Not sure it will even work for you.

If you want to know if it will work, I recommend trying it yourself! You have the schema already.

For user permissions, I recommend using the `alanning:roles` package. That should solve your issues.

Comment: Getting the user id manually and then updating the collection, as an array of strings, not as associated userid's

Comment: I don't know what you're saying. Is that a question or a statement?

Comment: It is a statement, on how I solved the problem, thanks for the help.